# WPF button is hidden but "CanExecute" method rises

Tags: c#, wpf, commandbinding

In my application I have some buttons inside a panel which is set to collapsed at some point, those buttons have a commandbinding with a `"CanExecute"` method. I would like to stop execute the logic inside the `"CanExecute"` method while the panel is not visible. 
If I can't see the button I don't need to spend resources to know if it can be executed.
I can try to bind the visibility of that panel to the `"CanExecute"` method, but I would like a solution for every button, so if they are not visible not waste time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the command binding when the button is not visibile.

> 1. Register a CommandBinding:
>      myUIelement.CommandBindings.Add(myCommand);
> 2. Unregister a CommandBinding:
>      myUIelement.CommandBindings.Remove(myCommand);
> 3. Unregister all CommandBindings: myUIelement.CommandBindings.Clear();

Comment: This is a good workarround, but I would have to write it in the code behind of the screen or a baseButton Class with similar behaviour

Comment: You could remove & set the command bindings by using styles and triggers in the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Object Type if it has parameters

i.e.

```
_someCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    p => someCommandExecute((someObject)p),
                    p => p is someObject);
```

or try validating the value if it does not have parameters

```
_someCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    p => someCommandExecute((someObject)p),
                    p => someObject != null);
```

i'm not sure if you're trying to do something like this but if you can post some sample of your code it will be helpful.

This might also help you https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/